# PHP socket programming for Diameter protocol

Tags: php, sockets, diameter-protocol

I have to integrate a Diameter protocol based API for mobile billing in my PHP application and the Diameter client and the server has been established on servers.

My questions is, can I use PHP socket functions in order to make request ? If not, is there any other way to call requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets is the standard way to initiate any connection from PHP, or any other language.